# repository is announced but not listed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I sent a message to announce a repository(called "dlut-ros-pkg ") via mailing list three days ago.

The "dlut-ros-pkg" repository is available at:

https://github.com/ZhuangYanDLUT/dlut-ros-pkg.git.

However,there is no message on the mailing list,and my repository isn't added to the indexer.

Is there anyone who can tell me why? Did I do something wrong when indexing my repository for Documentation Generation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60143/repository-is-announced-but-not-listed/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2013-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For `ros-users`, I'm not sure why your e-mail isn't sent but have you sent from the address you registered?

For package listing, you need to follow [certain steps here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved#Create_Your_Own_.2A-ros-pkg_Repository), not just sending an e-mail.

---

Update) Did you by any chance try to send e-mails from the website of `nabble.com`? If so that doesn't work. See [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/60254/some-e-mails-not-delivered-to-ros-users/?answer=60268#post-id-60268).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-07**:
I use the Github's e-mail.Or should I use another email?The address I registered? Do you mean the Github's address or the ros-users's address?

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-07**:
And I followed the steps here:http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-07**:
`ros-users` mailinglist & `github` repository have nothing in common. When you send an e-mail to `ros-users`, try using the address you registered [here](https://code.ros.org/mailman/listinfo/ros-users).

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-07**:
And for pkg listing, I don't see your `dlut-ros-pkg` in `pul request`s. Are you sure you did `6. Create Your Own *-ros-pkg Repository` in the link you sent?

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-07**:
Yes,I did 6. Create Your Own *-ros-pkg Repository.I will do it once more to check if I do something wrong.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-07**:
Now I see your pull request.

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-07**:
How can I see the repositories in pull requests?And must I subscribe to the ros-users before I send the message?Must I use the email address which I use to subscribe to the ros-users?

**Comment by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on 2013-04-07**:
How long will it take to have my pull request serviced?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-08**:
Please consider opening new questions. Asking too many in comment area isn't appropriate especially because this area isn't as visible to other people as questions.